# VS2015: Variadic template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, visual-studio-2015

This code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct Is_Admitted {
    constexpr static bool value = Is_Admitted<Head>::value && Is_Admitted<Tail...>::value;
};

template<>
template<typename T>
struct Is_Admitted<T> : public std::false_type{};

template<> struct Is_Admitted<int> : public std::true_type{};
template<> struct Is_Admitted<double> : public std::true_type{};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Is_Admitted<int, double>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << Is_Admitted<int, char>::value << '\n';
}
```

- compiles and run fine under [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8e00127e8ceb6060) (>=4.7, with c++11, c++14 or c++17 support enabled)
- compiles with a warning and run fine with [clang 3.6](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d77256fbd71fc2bf) (with c++11, c++14 or c++17 support enabled)
- does **not** compile under VS2015RC (or Preview) with the following errors:

(error descriptions are translated in English by myself as I was not able to set English as compiler language, so they might mismatch with original ones)

```
error C2910: 'Is_Admitted<T,>': impossible to perform explicit specialization
error C2065: 'value': undeclared identifier
error C2976: 'Is_Admitted': insufficients template arguments
error C2131: constant expression does not return any value
```

Which compiler is right and which one is wrong? Is that code compliant to either c++11, c++14 or c++17 standard?

And what is the right way to do what I'm trying to do, that is a variadic type function that returns true only if all template type parameters are of some admitted types?

Comment: That 'template<>' is extra

Comment: @DieterLücking Oh my! I've added that because I was pretty sure VS was giving me error without it, but it's NOT true. You're right, thanks. The error was a typo in the cpp file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `template<>` here:

```
template<>   // <===
template<typename T>
struct Is_Admitted<T> : public std::false_type{};
```

Your code gives me the same error via [webcompiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/). 
Simply remove it and it compiles fine. I do not understand how this compiles on either gcc or clang.

Two `template`  declarations are only necessary when you're defining a member template of a class template outside of the class definition, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    template <typename U>
    void bar();
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
void Foo<T>::bar() { ... }
```